# Python: Finding The Longest/Shortest Sentence In A Random Paragraph?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and need 2 functions to find **the longest and shortest** sentence (in terms of word count) in **a random paragraph**. For example, if I choose to put in this paragraph:

"Pair your seaside escape with the reds and whites of northern California's wine country in Jenner. This small coastal city in Sonoma County sits near the mouth of the Russian River, where, all summer long, harbor seals and barking California sea lions heave themselves onto the sand spit, sunning themselves for hours. You can swim and hike at Fort Ross State Historic Park and learn about early Russian hunters who were drawn to the area's herds of seal for their fur pelts. The fort's vineyard, with vines dating back to 1817, was one of the first places in California where grapes were planted."

The output for this should be **36** and **16** with 36 meaning there are 36 words in the longest sentence and 16 words in the shortest sentence.

Comment: Any code you tried so far?

Comment: First, figure out how to tokenize by sentence. Then work on comparing word lengths by tokenizing each sentence by word.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the string by the full stop character '.' Then splitting those sentences by space characters then counting the elements. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: generally in stack overflow people like to see you attempt the question before asking for help. This problem can be solved by tokenizing by "." to get the sentences then by " " to get the number of words.

Comment: I have tried finding the total number of words, total sentences, and average words per sentence to somehow know what to do next but I'm stuck there. Here are my codes so far: 

1.  Total number of words in the input file.
for line in input_file:
    for words in line.split():
        words = words.replace('?','').replace('!','').replace(".","")
        words = words.lower()
print len(words)

2. Total number of sentences in the input file.
print line.count(".")

3. Average number of words (float) per sentence.
print float(len(line.split()))/float(line.count("."))

The outputs are 103 ,4, 25.75

Comment: I know it has something to do with comparing word numbers but I have not been able to structure the codes.

Comment: there is more to your problem then you think, how you decide what a paragraph is programmatically?

Comment: Oh, for that, I assume all sentences end with a “.”, “?”, or “!”.

Comment: but what about a paragraph, do you only have a single paragraph or many different paragraphs on a single page,if so how do you decide where  one starts/end and another starts?

Comment: Yes, 1 paragraph is all and it starts with an upper case letter and ends with a “.”, “?”, or “!”. Anyway, the answer from PaulD is pretty much what I'm looking for. All I need is a start and I'll try more.

Answer (score 4):

```
def MaxMinWords(paragraph):
    numWords = [len(sentence.split()) for sentence in paragraph.split('.')]
    return max(numWords), min(numWords)
```

EDIT : As many have pointed out in the comments, this solution is far from robust. The point of this snippet is to simply serve as a pointer to the OP.

Comment: Wouldn't `min` return `0` incorrectly due to the last `.` in the paragraph after applying the `split('.')`?

Comment: paragraphs can contain `.` so I cannot see how splitting on `.` will work

Comment: I forgot to add more info, I assume all sentences end with a “.”, “?”, or “!”

Comment: Many dots `'.'` do not terminate a sentence e.g., <-- see two dots. Many words are not separated by space in a text. <-- see the last word is not separated by space.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for the tip about using `key`! I agree that this solution is far from robust. My guess was that OP needed help knowing how to tokenize stuff and that was what I was trying to illustrate. Let me add that to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You need a way to split the paragraph into sentences and to count words in a sentence. You could [use `nltk` package](http://www.nltk.org/) for both:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize # $ pip install nltk

sentences = sent_tokenize(paragraph)
word_count = lambda sentence: len(word_tokenize(sentence))
print(min(sentences, key=word_count)) # the shortest sentence by word count
print(max(sentences, key=word_count)) # the longest sentence by word count
```

Comment: This is the way to go in terms of robust code that handles most exceptions. (It's only useful if this question isn't for homework, because otherwise they probably aren;t supposed to be using NLTK.)

Comment: Ha this one shut up pedants;)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As has been mentioned in the comments below, programmatically determining what constitutes the sentences in a paragraph is quite a complex task. However, given the example you provided, I have elucidated a nice start to perhaps solving your problem below.

First, we want to tokenize the paragraph into sentences. We do this by splitting the text on every occurrence of a `.` (period). This returns a list of strings, each of which is a sentence.

We then want to break each sentence into its corresponding list of words. Then, using this list of lists, we want the sentence (represented as a list of words) whose length is a maximum and the sentence whose length is a minimum. Consider the following code:

```
par = "Pair your seaside escape with the reds and whites of northern California's wine country in Jenner. This small coastal city in Sonoma County sits near the mouth of the Russian River, where, all summer long, harbor seals and barking California sea lions heave themselves onto the sand spit, sunning themselves for hours. You can swim and hike at Fort Ross State Historic Park and learn about early Russian hunters who were drawn to the area's herds of seal for their fur pelts. The fort's vineyard, with vines dating back to 1817, was one of the first places in California where grapes were planted."

# split paragraph into sentences
sentences = par.split(". ")

# split each sentence into words
tokenized_sentences = [sentence.split(" ") for sentence in sentences]

# get longest sentence and its length
longest_sen = max(tokenized_sentences, key=len)
longest_sen_len = len(longest_sen)

# get shortest word and its length
shortest_sen = min(tokenized_sentences, key=len)
shortest_sen_len = len(shortest_sen)

print longest_sen_len
print shortest_sen_len
```

Comment: what about "The temp was 23.0 degrees today."?

Comment: The split is on what I presume to be the end of a sentence: a period followed by a space.

Comment: there are still many variations where a `.` could be in the middle of a paragraph and followed by a space.

Comment: In the middle of a paragraph or in the middle of a sentence? I can't really think of a grammatically correct sentence that features a period followed by a space in its content. A period followed by a space, found in a paragraph, presumably separates two sentences.

Comment: So you cannot have `I am Foo... ` in a paragraph?

Comment: Consider `I am foo. You are foo too.`. Using the split on `. `, we get two sentences: `["I am foo", "You are foo too."]. I am not sure what you're really going for?

Comment: I think you are underestimating the complexity, what about "I am foo?" Is that not a sentence? Or "I am batman!"?

Comment: Sure, it is very difficult to programmatically decipher the notion of a paragraph. But, under the constraints of the example given, I think that the code provided in my answer gives a good start to solving a much more complex problem.

Comment: To be honest I think conveying that fact to the OP would actually be the correct answer, I don't think they quite understand just how complex it is.

Comment: I buy that too. I will edit my answer. Thanks for the helpful dialogue.

Comment: No worries, +1 anyway, your answer is a step closer but I fear the OP has a lot of fun times ahead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is what I'm looking for. I'll take time to solve more complex problems based on your solution.

Comment: `.split(" ")` is not a robust way to split a sentence into words