# i need to calculate average sentence length in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

`avg_sentence_length` is function which calculate average length of a sentence

```
def avg_sentence_length(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text contains at least one sentence.

    A sentence is defined as a non-empty string of non-terminating 
    punctuation surrounded by terminating punctuation or beginning or 
    end of file. Terminating punctuation is defined as !?.

    Return the average number of words per sentence in text.   

    >>> text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
         'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
         'Of cabbages; and kings.\n',
         'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n',
         'and whether pigs have wings.\n']
    >>> avg_sentence_length(text)
    17.5
    """
```

Comment: Where do you stuck? Do you know how to split a text into sentences? Do you know how to split a sentence into words? Do you know how to compute the average knowing number of words in each sentence? See [`wordcount()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27662981/4279)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: it is true but please [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: Hi, this although you are very clear about what the function should do, you haven't shown what you tried already, and where you are stuck. That's probably why this got downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this?

```
def averageSentence(sentence):
    words = sentence.split()
    average = sum(len(word) for word in words)/len(words)
    print(average)

def main():
    sentence = input("Enter Sentence: ")
    averageSentence(sentence)
main()

output:
Enter Sentence: my name is something
4.25
```

I am using idle 3 and above. If you are working with python 2.7 or so, the code will be a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

We can use reduce and lambda.

```
from functools import reduce

def Average(l): 
    avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) / len(l)
    return(avg)

def AVG_SENT_LNTH(File):
    
    SENTS = [i.split() for i in open(File).read().splitlines()]
    Lengths = [len(i) for i in SENTS]
    return(Average(Lengths))


print("Train\t", AVG_SENT_LNTH("Train.dat"))
```

Though the splitting process is totally conditional.

Answer (score 0):

```
import doctest
import re


def avg_sentence_length(text):
    r"""(list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text contains at least one sentence.

    A sentence is defined as a non-empty string of non-terminating
    punctuation surrounded by terminating punctuation or beginning or
    end of file. Terminating punctuation is defined as !?.

    Return the average number of words per sentence in text.

    >>> text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
    ... 'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
    ... 'Of cabbages; and kings.\n',
    ... 'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n',
    ... 'and whether pigs have wings.\n']
    >>> avg_sentence_length(text)
    17.5
    """
    terminating_punct = "[!?.]"
    punct = r"\W"  # non-word characters
    sentences = [
        s.strip()  # without trailing whitespace
        for s in re.split(
            terminating_punct,
            "".join(text).replace("\n", " "),  # text as 1 string
        )
        if s.strip()  # non-empty
    ]

    def wordcount(s):
        """Split sentence s on punctuation
        and return number of non-empty words
        """
        return len([w for w in re.split(punct, s) if w])

    return sum(map(wordcount, sentences)) / len(sentences)


# test the spec. I just made the docstring raw with 'r'
# and added ... where needed
doctest.run_docstring_examples(avg_sentence_length, globals())
```

Answer (score 0):

use word_tokenize to find the words and then use a list comprehension to find alpha and digit words.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
from functools import reduce
text = ['The time has come, the Walrus said\n',
     'To talk of many things: of shoes - and ships - and sealing wax,\n',
     'Of cabbages; and kings.\n',
     'And why the sea is boiling hot;\n',
     'and whether pigs have wings.\n']

sentences = [ [word for word in word_tokenize ( sent ) if word.isalpha() or 
word.isdigit()] for sent in text]

counts=[]
for sentence in sentences:
    counts.append(len(sentence))

#https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/
#takes the first two sequences of the list and adds then gets the next sequence and accumulates it until end of list.

def Average(list_counts): 
    avg = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list_counts) / len(list_counts)
    return(avg)

print("Average words in the sentence is", Average(counts))
```

output:

```
 [['The', 'time', 'has', 'come', 'the', 'Walrus', 'said'], ['To', 'talk', 'of', 'many', 'things', 'of', 'shoes', 'and', 'ships', 'and', 'sealing', 'wax'], ['Of', 'cabbages', 'and', 'kings'], ['And', 'why', 'the', 'sea', 'is', 'boiling', 'hot'], ['and', 'whether', 'pigs', 'have', 'wings']]

 [7, 12, 4, 7, 5]

 Average words in the sentence is 7.0
```

Answer (score -3):

I have edited the code a bit in this answer but it **should** work (I uninstalled Python so I can't test sorry. (It was to make space on this rubbish laptop that only started with 28GB!) ) This is the code:

```
def findAverageSentenceLength(long1, medium2, short3):
    S1LENGTH = long1.length
    S2LENGTH = medium2.length
    S3LENGTH = short3.length

    ADDED_LENGTHS = S1LENGTH + S2LENGTH + S3lENGTH
    AVERAGE = ADDED_LENGTHS / 3

    print("The average sentence length is", AVERAGE, "!")
long1input = input("Enter a 17-30 word sentence.")
medium2input = input("Enter a 10-16 word sentence.")
short3input = input("Enter a 5-9 word sentence.")

findAverageSentenceLength(long1input, medium2input, short3input)
```

Hope this helps.

***PS: This WILL only work in Python 3***

Comment: Where do you split a text into sentences? Where do you split a sentence into words? Where does the method `length` come from?